# C# Entity Framework SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
class Student
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Student's name.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Student's ID
        /// </summary>
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string StudentID{get; set; }
}

class Course
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string nm { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Lecturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Campus { get; set; }
}

class StudentsCourses
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string nm { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

and corresponding tables in SQL Server. Entity Framework and the models are working perfectly, but now I want to cross check data from two tables, students and courses.

I wrote:

```
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("SELECT Students.StudentID,Students.StudentName").Append(" FROM Students, StudentsCourses");
st.Append(" WHERE Students.StudentID=StudentsCourses.StudentID AND StudentsCourses.CourseName='").Append(course).Append("'");

List<Student> Try = DataLayer.Students.SqlQuery(st.ToString()).ToList<Student>();
```

but it throws an exception saying

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

How can I run this query in SQL or in LinQ? My final goal is to get a list of students that study a given course name.

Comment: You need spaces. For example, between "StudentName" and "FROM".

Comment: `.StudentName").Append("FROM` will result in `StudentNameFROM` so make spaces

Comment: By the way, why are you writing your own SQL queries? That goes against the whole idea of using entity framework in most cases.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Because I dont know other way to do it..

Comment: @Erez, I suggest that you go though some tutorial before you use entity framework. In most projects, the time you will save by using the entity framework features is much more than the time you need to learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with appending strings.  Just use one long string (a string in C# can have line breaks) and use parameters (and a `JOIN`):

```
string sql = @"SELECT Students.StudentID,Students.StudentName
               FROM Students  
               INNER JOIN StudentsCourses
                  ON Students.StudentID=StudentsCourses.StudentID 
               WHERE StudentsCourses.CourseName=@courseName";

List<Student> Try = DataLayer.Students
                             .SqlQuery(sql, new SqlParameter("@courseName", course))
                             .ToList();
```

The equivalent Linq query (if you don't have navigation properties) would be something like

```
List<Student> Try = (  
    from s in DataLayer.Students
    join c in DataLayer.StudentsCourses
      on s.StudentID equals c.StudentID
    where c.CourseName = course
    select s).ToList();
```

Comment: OK, Now new Exception:
The value of a property that is part of an object's key does not match the corresponding property value stored in the ObjectContext.  This can occur if properties that are part of the key return inconsistent or incorrect values or if DetectChanges is not called after changes are made to a property that is part of the key.

Even though StudentID is defined as key both in the table and in the model. In the model its string and in the table its nvarchar(9)..

Comment: Are there more columns in `Student` that just ID and Name? I believe you have to output all columns if you are projecting to an entity type.  Is there a reason you're writing SQL directly instead of using Linq and Navigation properties?  That may solve both problems.

Comment: @D Stanley, mainly because I don't really know LinQ, searched google a bit and didn't found..

Comment: And thats all the columns, ID and Name, both in model and table

Comment: does the error occur on .ToList() or later in the code, like in .SaveChanges()?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro That's ok, the final problem was with my model, at the get set of the ID. Now it's working. Thanks.